# AZUR - Export Using BCP with Query

Tags: sql, select, azure, database-connection, bcp

I want to export data from a database Azur to an Excel file.
To do this, i use the command :

**bcp [DatabaseName].[Table] OUT C:...\Test_Export.xls  -c -U UserName@ServerName.database.windows.net -S tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net -P xxxxxxxx**

--> It Works

BUT, when i want do the same with SQL Query in the command, like this :

**bcp "Select field1, Field2 FROM [dbo].[ForecastTrialDisag]" QUERYOUT C:..\Test_Export.xls -d [DataBaseName] -c -U UserName@ServerName.database.windows.net -S tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net -P xxxxxx**

I have errors :

SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database 
"[DataBaseName]" requested by the login. The login failed.

SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'UserName'.

I don't understand why it doesn't work with a SQL query.  UserName, databaseName and password are OK.

Thank you for your help,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I believe the username is in the format of: "user@server" without the "databases.windows.net" part at the end.

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If the password is a strong one - contains punctuation for example, in my case I had a * and and ^ character in the password - than the use of double quotes for the password is needed:

bcp "Select field1, Field2 FROM [dbo].[ForecastTrialDisag]" QUERYOUT C:..\Test_Export.xls -d [DataBaseName] -c -U UserName@ServerName.database.windows.net -S tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net -P "xxxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some hours by using the main db admin user define in Azure and never got it to work - I'm sure I was missing something simple.

What got me over the hump was to use SQL and `CREATE USER` plus `GRANT` a user *inside* of SQL, the kind of user that's not apparently visible in the Azure portal but is easily visible inside of SQL Management Studio.

This worked super well for me.